# Multiple Charts w/ Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm having some trouble while trying to display more than two charts using Chart.js. By now, I have to charts loading on the same file, but when I tryed to add one more, those logs appeared on my console:

[image]

I did a jsbin so you guys can check the code:

```
Link: https://jsbin.com/yibutifodo/1/edit?html,js,output
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your bin does not throws errors and shows charts. Maybe you forgot some `datasets` part or some other?

Comment: @Justinas i checked my code again i dont think i missed something